# Ionic Toggle Background Color Not Working

Tags: ionic-framework, colors, background, toggle

I have four ionic toggles and the color of one of them is not calculated/shown correctly:

SASS Variables:

```
instruct: #74b230,
partic: #5076f1,
lock: #ff6600,
workplace: #bda7de
```

HTML

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngIf="this.filterpopoptions.get(filterpopoveroptions.HASPARTIC)">
      <ion-label>Teilnahmen</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="this.data.partic" color="partic"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="this.filterpopoptions.get(filterpopoveroptions.HASINSTRUCT)">
      <ion-label>Referententätigkeiten</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="this.data.instruct" color="instruct"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf="this.filterpopoptions.get(filterpopoveroptions.HASWORKPLACE)">
      <ion-label>Ausbildungsstationen</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="this.data.workplace" color="workplace"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item *ngIf=" this.filterpopoptions.get(filterpopoveroptions.HASLOCK)">
      <ion-label>Nichtverfügbarkeiten</ion-label>
      <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="this.data.lock" color="lock"></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Solved the problem by using a darker shade of the color. The color was too light to calculate a background color.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by using a darker shade of the color. The color was too light to calculate a background color.